# Creating function to fill in missing values with previous values in R

Tags: r, function

I am trying to create a filter that uses the previous value to fill in a missing value, for a maximum of two missing values (x_i+1 and x_i+2) filled in with the same value (x_i).

The first function I put together had issues with boundaries, so I took a few other attempts. Below are two of them. All of my attempts have failed tremendously -- most of the errors are

> "object x not found" or "unexpected } in"

```
fillfun <- function(x){
  for(i in seq_along(x[["reg"]])){
    if (is.na(x[["reg"]][[i]])) {
      if (is.na(x[["reg"]][[i+1]]) && is.na(x[["reg"]][[i+2]])) (x[["reg"]][[i]] <- NA)
          else (for(i > 1){ 
            if(is.na(x[["reg"]][[i+1]]) && is.na(x[["reg"]][[i-1]])) (x[["reg"]][[i]] <- NA) })

          else (for(i > 2){
            if (is.na(x[["reg"]][[i-1]]) && is.na(x[["reg"]][[i-2]])) (x[["reg"]][[i]] <- NA) })

     else (x[["reg"]][[i]] <- x[["reg"]][[i-1]])
      }
  }
  return(x)
}


#another attempt 

g <- rep(NA, each=34)
cust <- rep(NA, each=34)
reg <- rep(NA, each=34)
arti <- rep(NA, each=34)
mch0s <- rep(NA, each=34)
yrwk <- rep(NA, each=34)
regpr <- rep(NA, each=34)

fillfun <- function(x){
  g <- rep(NA, each=34)
  cust <- rep(NA, each=34)
  reg <- rep(NA, each=34)
  arti <- rep(NA, each=34)
  mch0s <- rep(NA, each=34)
  yrwk <- rep(NA, each=34)
  regpr <- rep(NA, each=34)

  for(i in seq_along(x[["reg"]])){


    ifelse( (is.na(x[["reg"]][[i]])) , #cond
            (ifelse( (is.na(x[["reg"]][[i+1]]) && is.na(x[["reg"]][[i+2]])), (x[["reg"]][[i]] <- NA) ), 
            ifelse(((i > 1) && (is.na(x[["reg"]][[i+1]]) && is.na(x[["reg"]][[i-1]]))), (x[["reg"]][[i]] <- NA) ), 
            ifelse(((i >2) && (is.na(x[["reg"]][[i-1]]) && is.na(x[["reg"]][[i-2]]))), (x[["reg"]][[i]] <- NA) ), #                  (x[["reg"]][[i]] <- x[["reg"]][[i-1]])))), (g <- x[["reg"]][[i]]))

    cust <- x[["customer"]][[[i]]]
    reg <- x[["region"]][[[i]]]
    arti <- x[["article"]][[[i]]]
    mch0s <- x[["mch0"]][[[i]]]
    yrwk <- x[["yearwk"]][[[i]]]
    regpr <- x[["reg"]][[[i]]]


  }
  return(list(customer=cust, region=reg , article=arti, mch0=mch0s, yearwk=yrwk, reg=regpr, newreg=g))
}
```

Here are a few samples of the data that I need this function to work on. Keep in mind these vectors are in a list in a list in a list in a list, so I will be using nested `lapply()` to run the fill-in function.

```
c(NA, NA, 3.37, NA, 3.37, 3.37, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.97, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.37, 3.37, NA, 3.34, 3.37, 3.37, 3.37, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)

c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.48, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)

c(4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, NA, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, NA, NA, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48, 4.48)
```

I welcome a wholly new approach to this. Many thanks in advance for all help.

Comment: Have you checked `na.locf` from `zoo`

Comment: are you looking for `fill` from `tidyr`?

Comment: @akrun Both of these look promising, but do they allow me to specify that the filling-in should not go beyond 2 NA's forward? My concern is that if I have one value followed by a sequence of NA's, that the whole sequence will be filled with that first value, which is not what I want.

Comment: @Onyamub same as above comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach that does not depend on extra packages:

```
test <- c(NA, NA, 3.37, NA, 3.37, 3.37, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.97, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.37, 3.37, NA, 3.34, 3.37, 3.37, 3.37, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)

n.steps <- 2

tmp <- embed( c(rep(NA,n.steps), test), n.steps+1)

result <- apply(tmp, 1, function(x){
  x[!is.na(x)][1]
})

cbind(test, result)
```

The code could be converted to a function to use within other `*apply` functions.  This does create multiple copies of the vector, so could be inefficient for very long vectors.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is perfect! Thank you! Could you please explain what the `embed` function does, and how a value is selected from the two new vectors? I have read the documentation and understand that the matrix is created, but the selection of the most recent carried-over value (i.e from i-1 instead of i-2) is stumping me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit: I actually got it! It applies the replacement function one column at a time, and only applies the i-2 value when there is no i-1 value. Cool. Thanks again!